# Bootstrap Responsive Design Fails with Web Forwarding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, redirect

I have adapted a bootstrap template from Start Bootstrap for my business.  This works fine in all browsers and in different formats - smart phones etc.  The site is www.opriskconsultant.com.  I have another domain name, twolyonsconsulting.co.uk, for which I have set up web forwarding to the main domain.  The responsive features work ok on my pc with Chrome and Edge, but not on my iPhone.

I have had the hosting company check the set up on the server side, and that seems fine, and I've searched for a solution without success.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are using a framed redirect, which essentially loads up the target website in an iFrame.

Doing so loses any responsive capabilities. What you are best doing, is changing your web forwarding method to actually forward to the new URL using a non-framed redirect.

This will then properly load up the target URL in the users browser, and all the responsive capabilities that go with it.

Comment: Lee - thanks for your answer.  I've changed the redirect from "masked" to a 301, and it now works.  I'm surprised the hosting company didn't tell me to do that!

Comment: They wouldn't necessarily know which is best for SEO, they probably just tried to give you the simplest solution. It's probably obvious anyway, but just wanted to point out, that the end user will see the domain name change as they get redirected.