# Forwarded URL renders the webpage in half the height as normal for a Flutter Web app hosted in Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, redirect, flutter-web, html-rendering

I have a firebase hosted Flutter Web application which is a game. Since the URL for the Firebase hosted site (https://jw-daily.web.app) is difficult to remember for users, I bought a domain name (joinedwords.com) and redirected the URL to the firebase hosted site.

Problem is that when I type the domain URL i.e. joinedwords.com, the website renders in only half the height like below:

[image]

However, if I type the original URL (https://jw-daily.web.app) in the browser, the webpage renders in full like below:

[image]

All that I have done is with my domain provider, I have set a forward with masking of joinedwords.com => https://jw-daily.web.app/

I looked up all the other solutions around why a webpage is rendering in half. However most of them are asking to make changes to the code and I don't want to do that since the original URL is working fine. Incidentally this issue is happening **only on mobile browsers** and not happening on desktop. In desktop, the website renders correctly regardless of which URL  is typed.

Please suggest if you are aware of how we can solve this problem. Here is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A Daily Word Game">
  <meta image="" />
  <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joint.words/joined-xxx.png"  
  property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joint.words/joined-xxx.png" 
  property ="og:image:alt" content="Joined Words Logo" 
  property="og:image:type" content="image/png"  
  />
<!-- 
  property="og:image:width" content="100" 
  property="og:image:height" content="100" 
-->

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Joined Words">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/joint.words/joined-256.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

  <title>Joined Words</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX" />
  />
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: xxxxxxxxx -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxxxx');
</script>
<!-- Event snippet for Website traffic conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js?version=1';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';  
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/9.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/9.0.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize app -->
  <script src="main.dart.js?version=15 " type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to the issue I was facing. Here is the link to the same:
[Bootstrap Responsive Design Fails with Web Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088384/bootstrap-responsive-design-fails-with-web-forwarding)

> This is because you are using a framed redirect which essentially loads up the target website in an iFrame. Doing so loses any responsive capabilities. What you are best doing is changing your web forwarding method to actually forward to the new URL using a non-framed redirect. This will then properly load up the target URL in the users browser and all the responsive capabilities that go with it.